# Windows Batch Script: search string within folder and subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to search string "@B-ADD|496|" within my main folder and its subfolders. however, the below script unable to search my subfolders.
please kindly help

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('findstr /S "@B-ADD|496|" C:\Users\william\Desktop\New Folder\*.txt') DO (
  move "C:\Users\wee-liem.wong\Desktop\New Folder\*.txt"   "C:\Users\william\Desktop\New Folder (2)"
)

pause
```

Comment: You are searching a string in what? the paths or file names, or the file contents? please clarify!

Comment: Searching string in txt files. the path: C:\Users\william\Desktop\NewFolder\    ; subfolder: C:\Users\william\Desktop\NewFolder\test\

Comment: Please add this information to your question by editing the post... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`findstr`**

Your paths include spaces. You are correctly quoting them in the `move` command, but not in the `findstr` command. Without quotes the path where to search is not found so no file can be found.

If you want to process the list of files found containing the string , you will need to indicate to `findstr` that you don't want the text found, only the file names where the text has been found. Include `/M` in the list of switches used in `findstr`

Also, depending on what the content of the string is, `findstr` will not behave as you could expect. Some characters will make the search string be handled as regular expression or be splitted on spaces. It is better to indicate what the search is.

So, the `findstr` should look something like

```
findstr /s /m /l /c:"@B-ADD|496|" "C:\Users\william\Desktop\New Folder\*.txt"
```

Search in subdirectories (`/s`) returning only file names (`/m`) the literal (`/l` but in this case can be omitted as `/c` implies by default a string literal) the indicated string (`/c:"....."`)

**`for /f`**

With the `findstr` command corrected, you will retrieve a list of matching files that will be iterated by the `for /f`. If you want to move *only* these found files, it makes no sense to include a full path and a wildcard in the source of the `move` command. You should use as source `"%%~fA"` to retrieve the full path of the element being referenced by the `for` replaceable parameter (`%%A` in your code), that is, the full path to found file.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=C:\Users\wee-liem.wong\Desktop\NewFolder"
    set "target=C:\Users\william\Desktop\NewFolder(2)"

    if not exist "%target%\" md "%target%\"

    for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
        findstr /s /m /l /c:"@B-ADD|496|" "%source%\*.txt"
    ') do move /y "%%~fA" "%target%"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment,
I done some modification on it. however, still unable to find in my subfolder
Main: C:\Users\wee-liem.wong\Desktop\NewFolder\  ;
subfolder: C:\Users\wee-liem.wong\Desktop\NewFolder\Test\    ;


FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('findstr /s /m /l /c:"@B-ADD|496|" "C:\Users\william\Desktop\NewFolder\*.txt"') DO (
move "C:\Users\wee-liem.wong\Desktop\New Folder\*.txt" "C:\Users\william\Desktop\NewFolder(2)"
    )
pause

Comment: @william123456, Your changes missed a backslash and the part about the `for` replaceable parameter reference. Code included, adapt to your needs.